# Wagtailtrans 2.2 install fails

Tags: wagtail

I've read all the tutorials for setting up wagtailtrans 2.2.
I set the languages in my base.py according to the tutorials. I cannot install wagtailtrans. I get error output about Pillow.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/private/var/folders/2f/rfv6v0056c58r9w83rzw30n00000gn/T/pip-install-yn4w0un0/pillow_5e7e668306de465dbfb8730b888585f9/setup.py", line 918, in <module>
    raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)
__main__.RequiredDependencyException:

The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

Please see the install instructions at:
   https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
```

I tried to reinstall Pillow according to their docs and reinstall wagtailtrans but it doesn't work. The error doesn't mention anything about wagtailtrans but when I go to makemigrations I get the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wagtailtrans'

I haven't found anything online about this so any help would be most appreciated. Sorry if this is a N00b question

Comment: It says that your OS is missing `zlib` library that it needs to compile Pillow. It has nothing to do with `wagtailtrans`. What's your OS? Is it Windows or Mac or maybe you're running it in Docker?

Comment: Mac OS. I was not running in docker. just in Pipenv. I didn't think they were related but then the wagtailtrans doesn't install so I guessed there was some dependency

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a Mac, install Xcode tools, amongst other useful libraries, it will also bring the missing `zlib`. To install Xcode tools, run the following command in a terminal:

```sh
xcode-select --install
```